# How to merge two objects with Math operation for the same properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, frontend

For example I have two objects

```
const obj = {
  CRITICAL: 0,
  ERROR: 1,
  INFO: 0,
  WARNING: 0,
};

const obj = {
  CRITICAL: 0,
  ERROR: 0,
  INFO: 0,
  WARNING: 1,
};
```

I want to combine them into one object with the sum of each properties  like this

```
{
      CRITICAL: 0,
      ERROR: 1,
      INFO: 0,
      WARNING: 1,
    };
```

The approach I came up with is

```
Object.keys(obj).reduce((prev,curr)=>{
  prev[curr] = obj[curr] + obj2[curr];
  return prev
},{});
```

However I think there are better ways of doing this. Can you guys give me some other approaches.

Comment: What constitutes "better"? Your current function operation is clean, clear, and sensible.

Comment: @zfrisch Hi, I was thinking of making this more robust. Currently this approach only works if both objects have the exact number of properties.

Comment: What should happen if one of the objects has fewer properties than the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't much different than your version, but I think it's slightly cleaner.

It also ensures that the resulting object has all of the keys from both objects, and defaults to 0 for the `obj2` value when `obj2` is missing a key that's in `obj`.

```js
const obj = {
  CRITICAL: 0,
  ERROR: 1,
  INFO: 0,
  WARNING: 0,
  OBJECT1: 1
}

const obj2 = {
  CRITICAL: 0,
  ERROR: 0,
  INFO: 0,
  WARNING: 1,
  OBJECT2: 1
}

console.log(
  Object.entries(obj).reduce(
    (prev, [key, value])=> {
      prev[key] = value + (prev[key] || 0)
      return prev
    },
    { ...obj2 } // spread to avoid mutating obj2
  )
)
```

Explanation: Here I have initialized the accumulator (`prev`) to a shallow clone of `obj2`. This way, we are guaranteed to have all of the properties that are in `obj2` remain in the resulting object (with their values unchanged when `obj` doesn't have a matching property).

I also default to zero for `obj2[key]` in case it's not found, guaranteeing that all properties in `obj` will be carried through to the resulting object (with their values unchanged when `obj2` doesn't have a matching property).

You could add some more safety by checking the types of the values to make sure they're numbers, but I think it's reasonably solid, otherwise.